# calling SSH Sudo Commands in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, server, sudo

I am trying to run the command while looping through
a series of sever addresses.

```
while read server
do
      ssh -t $sever "sudo md5sum $fileName >> hashes"
done < serverNamesFile
```

within a script in bash but i keep getting this error

> sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo

if I run the same line of commands  in the command line though, it works perfectly fine.

Can someone tell me why this keeps happening?

Comment: Are you running the script from the command line?

Comment: Yes, i am running the script through the command line shell

Comment: Is there any I/O redirection going on?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your entire script or at least the relevant part. It would be very helpful to see how you're running ssh--whether it's in a loop, or if there's redirection or piping involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. apparently looping through a series of servers inside a script causes the "TTY" error for SSH.

a better practice is to create a script that takes in the address of the server you want to SSH in and then pass in the commands that way. you can still loop through a series of file or commands by calling SSH each time and use this command:

```
while read stuff
do
ssh -qtt $severName " command"
done < $fileStuff
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably have

> Defaults requiretty

in your /etc/sudoers file.

As the option's name suggests, that will cause sudo to require a tty